# Get tags that are next to a specified tag in XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Using XSLT, how can I get all member names associated with the `tag` `A`?

```
    <letter>
      <tag>0-9</tag> 

      <member>
        <name>011</name>
        <type>Member</type>
      </member>

      <member>
        <name>2314</name>
        <type>Member</type>
      </member> 

    </letter>

    <letter>
       <tag>A</tag>

      <member>
        <name>Asia</name>
        <type>President</type>
      </member>

      <member>
        <name>Artie</name>
        <type>Vice 1</type>
      </member>
    </letter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an xpath predicate:

```
//letter[tag='A']/member
```

Comment: depends what you're going to do with the members, you could use this in a for-each like <xsl:for-each select="//letter[tag='A']/member"> but it kind of depends on what your context node is and what you intend to do with the result